# Is RxJava 2 Flowable hot or cold?

Tags: observable, rx-java

I used to think that RxJava 2's Flowable was designed to be "hot" and Observable "cold".  But I think that's wrong now - That Observable and Flowable are both cold but can be made hot e.g. by making either Connectable.  Is this correct?

Comment: With Flowable you can handle back-pressure with diffrent stragtegies. Observable cannot

Answer (score 4):

I think we should define element by element:

**Cold vs Hot**

In the case of `Observable` cold and hot, we could define that a cold is when an `Observable` emits the same defined events to whom it subscribes, for example `Observable.just (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` while hot could be events that could not be exactly the same all the time, for example the result of a query to the database or a request to server through retrofit.

Then we could define a `Flowable.just (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` or an `Observable.just (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` as cold, in this case there are just few elements and not being a sequence that will be continuously sending items, it would be worth keeping it as Observable.

Think in **cold** `Observable` as a music CD, you will always listen to the same songs and in the same order, no matter how many times you use it, while a **hot** `Observable` is like a radio station, you will regularly receive different information, maybe you subscribed late and finished the radio show you wanted to listen to or it's just different.

**Observable vs Flowable**

Now the main difference between an `Observable` and a `Flowable` is that **`Flowable` supports back pressure**, prevents loss of information in case it cannot consume the events as fast as it is receiving them.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)

**ConnectableObservable**

In the `ConnectableObservable` case, the `Publisher` begins to emit information to the subscribers after executing `ConnectableObservable::connect`, regardless of whether the observable sender is cold or hot.

**Then**

The important thing is to identify if it is necessary to use an Observable or a Flowable and according to how they emit their values ​​we can call it cold or hot.

The next book gave me a big push: [https://www.amazon.com/Learning-RxJava-Thomas-Nield/dp/1787120422](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1787120422)

Comment: "Now the main difference between an Observable and a Flowable is that Flowable supports back pressure" - this is not strictly true, in RxJava 1.x Observable was the one dealing with backpressure, whereas in RxJava 2.x handling of backpressure was moved to separate class, Flowable